# Java Script Error Message When I Open a Web Page

Tags: windows-xp, javascript

I receive an *Javascript* error message everytime I open a web page using *Firefox*.  The error message states:

```
Error: Type Error:netscape.security.PrivilegeManager is undefined.
```

What does it mean?  How do I clear it?  I tried updating Java and I still get the message.

Comment: Java has nothing to do with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Disable all extensions.  And then drill-down by re-enabling one extension (ie, AVG security tool-bar) at a time and reloading Firefox until you catch the error.

This issue is generally due to outdated extensions.